# std::map with a char[5] key that may contain null bytes

Tags: c++, stl, char, stdmap

The keys are binary garbage and I only defined them as `char`s because I need a 1-byte array.
They may contain `null` bytes.

Now problem is, when I have a two keys: `ab(0)a` and `ab(0)b` (`(0)` being a `null` byte), the `map` treats them as strings, considers them equal and I don't get two unique `map` entries.

What's the best way to solve this?

Comment: `char[5]` is a nonsensical key type for `std::map<>`. Why are you avoiding `std::string`/`std::vector<char>`/`std::array<char, 5>`?

Comment: How do you declare the map? How do you insert data into it?

Comment: Why do you declare a 5-byte key when you only need a 1-byte array?

Comment: @ildjarn: std::string because it ends on null bytes, std:vector because I didn't try it yet, and std:array because it worked like std::string.
@Rob: I meant an array of terms 1-byte each.

Comment: @GeorgeStephanos : I'm not sure what you mean by "ends on null bytes" -- `std::string` fully supports embedded null characters, as do `std::vector<>` and `std::array<>`...

Comment: @ildjarn: I meant exactly what happens in the question statement. The map ignores everything after the null byte when I try to insert a value and treats the two strings shown equal.

Comment: @ildjarn: apologies, strings do handle embedded null characters. I just didn't know I had to do it the way Nawaz said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use `std::string` as key:

```
//must use this as:
std::string key1("ab\0a",4); 
std::string key2("ab\0b",4); 
std::string key3("a\0b\0b",5); 
std::string key4("a\0\0b\0b",6);
```

Second argument should denote the size of the c-string. All of the above use this constructor:

```
string ( const char * s, size_t n );
```

[description](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/) of which is this:

> Content is initialized to a copy of the string formed by the first n characters in the array of characters pointed by s.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::array<char,5>` or maybe even better (if you want really to handle keys as binary values) `std::bitset`

Comment: I forgot to say I had already tried std::array and it worked just like char* and std::string. As for a std::bitset, I couldn't figure out how to write it to a file as raw data (I need that).

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use `char[5]` as your key, consider writing your own comparison class to compare between keys correctly. The `map` class requires one of these in order to organize its contents. By default, it is using a version that doesn't work with your key.

Here's a page on [the map class](http://cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/) that shows the parameters for `map`. You'd want to write your own `Compare` class to replace `less<Key>` which is the third template parameter to `map`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need to distinguish them and don't rely on a lexicographical ordering you could treat each key as uint64_t. This has the advantage, that you could easily replace std::map by a hashmap implementation and that you don't have to do anything by hand.

Otherwise you can also write your own comparator somehow like this:

```
class MyKeyComp
{
  public:
  operator()(char* lhs, char* rhs)
  {
    return lhs[0] == rhs[0] ? 
       (lhs[1] == rhs[1] ? 
       (lhs[2] == rhs[2] ? 
       (lhs[3] == rhs[3] ? lhs[4] < rhs[4]) 
       : lhs[3] < rhs[3]) 
       : lhs[2] < rhs[2]) 
       : lhs[1] < rhs[1]) 
       : lhs[0] < rhs[0];
  }
};
```

Comment: But, see [std::lexicographical_compare](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/lexicographical_compare/)

Comment: I do rely on ordering, and I thought I could only add a comparator for sorting (true if less, false if more).